# Namespace of Forms in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is it safe to put every form in my **presentation-layer** in the same namespace? (Might be a stupid question but i want to be sure).

Comment: Safe for what? It's not clear what you're trying to achive

Comment: Why you have such doubt?

Comment: You should partition your application if you know it will be a bigger one.

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces are to organize your code. If you have a few forms and you put them all in the same namespace, that is okay.

I would say if you have tons of screens, you eventually will lose overview of the code, and then it becomes important to organize your code. Usually you will split on funtionality, like *DataLayer*, *PresentationLayer*, etc., but you can do that for screen categories too (like *User*, *Article*).

To be clear, there is nothing safe or unsafe about using namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

It's not *unsafe*.

The purpose of namespaces is to:

- avoid running out of names (which must be unique), and
- avoid confusion between similarly named things.

For example, there are lots of things in lots of libraries with classes called "Node", "Record", "Entry", "Rule" or similar generic terms.

In general, if you always use two classes together and never apart, there is usually no reason to put them in different namespaces.